# Are system calls available in a chroot environment?

Tags: compiling, chroot, system-calls

I'm experiencing a lot of compilation errors regarding missing system calls (e.g. `error: '__NR_name_to_handle_at' undeclared (first use in this function)`) with different projects (ganesha 2.1.0 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/nfs-ganesha/) and qemu 2.0) compiling in a debian chroot on a Synology DS214 with DSM 5.0 with armv7l architecture - I know this is not an ideal compile environment. The pattern in the experienced errors and the lack of other information and/or a clear statement has driven me to ask this question.

The compilation succeeds on another machine, but this doesn't provide an answer to the question. I haven't taken the effort to set up a compilation environment outside chroot and I don't plan to. I know that cross compiling outside chroot on another machine provides a workaround for the compilation failures.

Comment: Generally, declaration errors indicate that you're missing header files. In this case you're likely missing kernel headers.

Comment: What version of `libc` are you using? Can you look in /usr/include/asm/unistd.h `#define __NR_name_to_handle_at`.